# Vuejs dynamic step set based on ranger value

Tags: vue.js, slider, range

What I would like to achive is to use a range slider with different step values based on where is the ranger knob is.

```
<input :step="loanRangeStep" id="loan_slider" max="150000000"
                               min="3000000"
                               type="range" v-model="loanValue" v-on:change="setSteps"/>
```

In the methods:

```
            setSteps() {
            if (this.loanValue < 20000000) {
                return this.loanRangeStep = 100000;
            } else if (this.loanValue > 20000000 && this.loanValue < 50000000) {
                return this.loanRangeStep = 500000;
            } else if (this.loanValue > 50000000) {
                return this.loanRangeStep = 1000000;
            } else {
                return this.loanRangeStep = 100000;
            }
        }
```

What is happening is when I move the knob on the slider the step is 100.000 at the whole time. If i mouseup in one of the ranges the step set corretly.

Is there any way to chenge the step value without the mouse click up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `v-on:input` instead of `v-on:change`.

Comment: You already given the right answer. when I was playing in snippet.

Answer (score 1):

`@change` will trigger only if you drap thought key or mouse up. Otherwise you have use `@input` to make it change.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    loanRangeStep:10,
    loanValue:200
  },
  methods:{
    setSteps() {
          console.log(this.loanValue);
            if (this.loanValue < 300) {
                return this.loanRangeStep = 10;
            } else if (this.loanValue >= 300 && this.loanValue < 500) {
                return this.loanRangeStep = 50;
            } else if (this.loanValue >= 500) {
                return this.loanRangeStep = 100;
            } else {
                return this.loanRangeStep = 100;
            }
        }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.com/libraries/rangeslider.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div>Value : {{loanValue}}</div>
<div>
<input :step="loanRangeStep" id="loan_slider" max="1500" min="200" type="range" v-model="loanValue" @input="setSteps"/>
</div>
</div>
```